# Record-triggered flow scheduled path

Tags: lightning

I am trying to use the scheduled path to trigger and email alert after a number of minutes/days but the flow keeps defaulting to 'Run immediately'. The error that keeps showing is "The flow can't run because nothing is connected to the Start element". Any idea why? (screenshot attached)

[image: scrrenshot]

Comment: Welcome to SFSE!. Please see [ask] on getting the most from the community. We're going to need a screen shot of your flow's entry point and scheduled path